# how to define the xpath to retrieve the value (span class - ng-binding)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML

```
<div id="nav" data-offset-top="100">
<div class="row top-space bor-box" ng-show="BindList.length > 0">
<span class="pull-left text-info dropdown">
<a id="Action" class="btn btn-link text-info" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Action 
<span class="caret"/>
</a>
 |
<span>
 |
<span>
 |
<span style="top: 2px; position: relative;">
Total Count:
<b class="ng-binding">23904</b>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Question
extract the `23904` value

my xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav']/div[1]/span[1]/span[3]/b")).getText();
```

output will be empty string, can any one point the issue in the above xpath, or please guide me

Comment: why don't you use `"//b[@class="ng-binding]"`?

Comment: try xpath - //*[@id="nav"]/div/span/span/span/span/b  and let me know if it works.

Comment: xpath is wrong, you can try with the xpath daniu or kapil mentioned above

Comment: yes @murthi is right,

Comment: Moving my comment to an answer. Try this and accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath:-

```
//div[@id='nav']//b[@class='ng-binding']/text()
```

It will return

```
23904
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[@class='ng-binding']")).getText();
```

Comment: thanks, used the above xpath, but till getting empty string

Comment: Please share the snapshot dear

Comment: try this //b[starts-with(@class=’ng-binding’)] in xpath

Comment: are u using sysout statment or not  System.out.printlndriver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[@class='ng-binding']")).getText());

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath amd lets see if it works for you -

```
//*[@id="nav"]/div/span/span/span/span/b
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[@class='ng-binding']")).getAttribute("innerText")
```